# Setup different kubernetes cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-container-service

I created an azure kubernetes cluster via "az acs create".
I exec an existing POD

```
kubectl exec -it mypod /bin/bash
```

and make a curl http://myexternlip.com/raw
The IP I get is the public ip address of the k8s-agents... So far so good.

Now I create an azure kubernetes cluster via "acs-engine".
Make the same "exec" as above-mentioned...
Now I can't find the IP in any azure component. Neither in the agents, nor in the load balancers.
Where is this IP configured?

Regards,
saromba

Comment: Yes. I can't find it in the resource group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should have the information you're looking for:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-kubernetes-load-balancing

In short, when you expose a service with type=loadbalancer, ACS creates a Public IP address resource that K8S uses.